# How to insert the current system date into a db column using mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have three *date fields in a table defined as VARCHAR(45) with a default value of '00-00-0000'. Each of the fields needs the default value of the current system time when a record is created.

I have changed one of the fields from VARCHAR(45) to TIMESTAMP with default of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, which works great.  I think I can only have a single field with Datatype TIMESTAMP per table.

How do I handle the other 2 fields in the tables? I would like to *CURRENT_TIMESTAMP them too.

Thanks

Comment: geez, obvious huh? i was only looking at the table structure, not thinking about using sql to handle that....

Comment: It's ok, can't be worse than answering a C# question with jQuery the other day... Guilty as charged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) function:

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (field1, field2) VALUES ('blahblah', now());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "NOW()" in a MySQL query to fill in the current time for a timestamp column.

Answer (score 1):

You can write Now() to the fields

```
INSERT INTO table (right_now) 
VALUES (Now()):
```